# How to recover deleted photos?

Tags: data-recovery, photos, delete

By mistake, I've accidentally deleted the folder where my phone camera saves the photos; I was trying to delete just a couple of them, but inadvertently the whole folder was selected, and all the pictures that were inside were lost; the folder was residing in the external SD card, not on the phone internal memory.

What is the best way to recover them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't write anything on your SD card.
Connect it to a PC using card reader or, USB

#### if you are using windows

use [Recuva recovery software](https://www.piriform.com/recuva)

### if you are using linux/ ubuntu

use [TestDisk app](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

Both of these software are free.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Easeus Data recovery software**

Here are the detailed instructions :[Easeus Website](http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery/card-recovery-software/recover-deleted-photos-pictures-from-sd-card.htm)