# How to recover data that was lost when clearing application data?

Tags: applications, data-recovery, photos

I was trying to free some space in my android device to install an application update. So I went to my applications and started deleting application data from them but for some stupid reason it didn't cross my mind that the photos taken with a particular app would count as application data. I would like to recover those photos. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: You could try a data recovery app, but most likely in modern devices it is just gone and not retrievable through normal means since most Android devices do not have that level access to the file system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover deleted photos?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/how-to-recover-deleted-photos)